# Passing member function that accepts void *

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, casting, member

I am working on code that needs to send a member function pointer to a logger method that accepts a void * as the parameter.  I cannot change it from void *.  I cannot use c++11 either.  Is there a way to get it to work without any warning.  For example:

logger.h

```
    #ifndef _LOGGER_H
    #define _LOGGER_H

    void logger( void *func );

    #endif /* _LOGGER_H */
```

logger.cpp

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include "logger.h"

    void logger( void *func )
    {
        printf("%lx\n", (unsigned long)func);
    }
```

testCase.cpp

```
    #include "logger.h"

    class myClass
    {
        public:
            void testCase( void );
    };

    void myClass::testCase( void )
    {
        /* This works on my compiler, but gives warning */
        /* warning: converting from 'void (myClass::*)()' to 'void*' */
        /* I know this is bad and wrong. */
        logger((void *)&myClass::testCase);

        /* This compiles without warning */
        /* But doesnt work the way I need, gives ffff*/
        void (myClass::*ptr)( void ) = &myClass::testCase;
        void *m_ptr = ptr;
        logger(m_ptr);
    }
```

logger.h and logger.cpp cannot be changed.

This is being run a VxWorks and I need the address to look up in the symbol table.  When I try the second way I get ffff.  Although I get a real address when using other compilers, its different for VxWorks.

Can you think of another way to get this to work.

[References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121320/get-memory-address-of-member-function)

Comment: You could pass a pointer a struct containing a member function pointer, or have it point to an address which contains a member function pointer (which are pretty much the same, one with more syntax sugar)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't make it happen. Standard prohibits converting pointers-to-members  to `void*`. The reason for this is their incompatibility with `void*` - they are usually double the size of the `void*`.

Your code has other issues as well, for example, `(unsigned long)func` is converting a `void*` to unsigned long, and this is undefined as well. For example, on many systems long is 32 bits in length, while `void*` is 64bit. To reliably convert `void*` to integer type, you need to use `uintptr_t` (provided your implementation has it).

Comment: The original code passed the member function as a string "myClass::testCase" and that was converted to the unsigned long.  We are trying to get rid of the old way and implement a new service.  passing a member function pointer to a logger.  The logger code was written in c and cannot be changed because it is being used in so many other places.  We wanted to find a way to pass the pointer.

Comment: @TylerGajewski, like I said, firstly you can't. Secondly, imagine you do it. What are you going to do with this pointer in C logger?

Comment: The actual logger is 2400 lines long so i simplified it a bit.  But ideally it doesn't use printf it uses the registers to print to a vx console and the user would use that address to look up in the symbol table.  The logger also accepts an ellipsis and format to output a string for debugging to the console.  So the output would be something like: `5649b0(This is a message)` Where then the user could copy that address and use it to look up in the symbol table.  The code get very complicated

Comment: @TylerGajewski, you would have very hard time looking up pointer to member in the symbol table. Do not forget about virtual functions!

Comment: My lead says that if we could get it to work even with the virtual function issue then it would still be an improvement over what we have.  The implementation i have with the first example works exactly like we want it to.  But where I work it is illegal to have warnings.

Comment: If I was able to change the logger to accept a member function pointer.  Could it be done if the logger is not in the same class as the calling function.  ex. `void logger( void (class::*)( void ) )` could the class be generic? ie. could it accept any class.

Comment: @TylerGajewski, you'd have to make your logger a template for this.

Comment: I wish i was allowed to use a template. But were using a very very old gcc compiler and templates aren't allowed.  Thank you for your help @SergeyA

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "double the size"; pointers are pointers and in my understanding, all pointers on a given system are the same size, regardless of what they point to...

However, looking in my copy of The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Edition, by Stroustrup (page 101):

> Occurrances of `void*s` at higher levers of the system should be viewed with suspicion because they are likely indicators of design errors.  Where used for optimization, `void*` can be hidden behind a type safe interface (§13.5, §24.4.2).
>
> Pointers to functions (§7.7) and pointers to members (§15.5) cannot be assigned to `void*s`.

Comment: You should remove the first part about all pointers being the same size; it's not true; member function pointers can be and usually are bigger than "standard" pointers. You learn something every day!

Comment: Your first sentence is plain wrong, you better remove it.